# Need to fill a html text with values from form. Is this the way?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a total beginner, so please lend me some rope here :)

I need to fill some text with different words, numbers, calculation-results etc. from a from.
This is what I came up with (just for one field/word), and it seems to work. But I wonder if this is the correct approach or if I need to look into some other functions?

Thanks for any advise/tips!

```js
const run = () => {
  let myWord = document.getElementById("myWord").value;
  document.getElementById("someWord").innerHTML = myWord;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form1" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="myWord" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="run()" name="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <p>The word I typed above is: <span id="someWord"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Depending on your intended functionality, you could also utilize [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to update the `span` every time the `input` value changes, rather than waiting for a button press. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event has a working example of possibly exactly what you're wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rule of thumb is: "If it works - leave it be :)". Your code work and that is what is important, specially for a beginner - This is how you learn things. If I analyze the method, using the .innerHTML is the right way to do so, when writing in plain Javascript.

If, later on, you'll work with Jquery (for instance), it will be a lot easier, and same thing could be accomplished in a "shorter" way by doing:

```
$('#someWord').html($('#myWord').val());
```

But till then, good job.!